# How to use regex for parsing

Tags: python, regex

I need to use regex preferably re.findall() or re.multiline() to parse any numbers in this inventory log any suggestions? Here is what I have so far.

Here is an example of an inventory log:

```
Processor               : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 0 @ 1.90GHz (24 cores/threads)

Memory                  : 65493MB

Controller Slot         : 0

BIOS                    : 3.0b 05/06/2014 3.2

mpt2sas0: LSISAS2308: FWVersion(16.00.01.00), ChipRevision(0x05), BiosVersion(07.33.00.00)

mpt2sas1: LSISAS2308: FWVersion(17.00.01.00), ChipRevision(0x05), BiosVersion(07.33.00.00)

compute node vpd: NA;NA;NA;

IPMI FW rev             : 2.29

Chassis Type            :  Other

Chassis Part Number     :  CSE-927ETS-R000NDBP

Chassis Serial          :  C92700325A00092

Board Mfg Date          :  Sun Dec 31 19:00:00 1995

Board Mfg               :  Supermicro

Board Product           :  IPMI 2.0

Board Serial            :  OM13BS013020

Board Part Number       :  X9DBS-F(-2U)

Product Manufacturer    :  Supermicro

Product Name            :   IPMI 2.0

Product Part Number     :  SSG-2027B-DE2R24L

Product Version         :

Product Serial          :  S13592923B11809

PCI Riser Card:

81:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS2308 PCI-Express 

Fusion-MPT SAS-2 (rev 05)

83:00.0 Ethernet controller: Chelsio Communications Inc T420-BT Unified Wire Ethernet 

Controller

83:00.1 Ethernet controller: Chelsio Communications Inc T420-BT Unified Wire Ethernet 

Controller

83:00.2 Ethernet controller: Chelsio Communications Inc T420-BT Unified Wire Ethernet 

Controller

83:00.3 Ethernet controller: Chelsio Communications Inc T420-BT Unified Wire Ethernet 

Controller

83:00.4 Ethernet controller: Chelsio Communications Inc T420-BT Unified Wire Ethernet 

Controller

83:00.5 SCSI storage controller: Chelsio Communications Inc T420-BT Unified Wire Storage 
Controller
83:00.6 Fibre Channel: Chelsio Communications Inc T420-BT Unified Wire Storage Controller
83:00.7 Ethernet controller: Chelsio Communications Inc Device 0000

-Hardware information

+Ethernet configuration
Chelsio T420-BT Card
version:   2.8.0.0
firmware-version: 1.9.23.0

plxnic0    00:10:b5:87:b0:01
eth3       00:07:43:15:fb:68
eth2       00:07:43:15:fb:60
eth1       00:25:90:8c:3a:23
eth0       00:25:90:8c:3a:22
bmc1       00:25:90:8c:15:2d    10.40.32.36
-Ethernet configuration

+Firmware Versions
, you are running a release image
This sdi release build was done by build on Sun Jul 13 2014 16:51:58
From /slave/jenkins/workspace/sdi_rls/dgcode
With git rev: e7fc81503edb567205e284cadef35f6bc5d0b7e6
```

---

```
   import re

   with warnings.catch_warnings():
   warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
   import sys

   sys.path.append("/home/build/sars")


   def rescanips():


 data = {}

  fileIN = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

line = fileIN.readline()

for line in file_obj:
    if ':' in line:
     pos = line.index(':')
     data[line[:pos].strip()] = line[pos + 1:].strip()

 for key in data: print key, ':', data[x]

 if key == "Processor":
     if data[x] != "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 v2 @ 2.20GHz (24 cores/threads)":
         sys.stderr.write("Should be Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 v2 @ 2.20GHz (24 cores/threads) but it is" + data[x] "\n")

  if key == "Memory":
      if data[x] != "81877MB":
      sys.stderr.write("Error in memory: should be 81877MB it is currently" + data[x] + "\n")

 if key == "Controller Slot":
     if data[x] != "0" or "1":
        sys.stderr.write("Invalid controller slot either should be 0 or 1 it is" + data[x] + "\n")

 if key == "BIOS":
     if data[x] != "3.0b 5/6/14 3.1":
        sys.stderr.write("The BIOS must be updated to 3.0b 5/6/14 3.1 it is currently" + data[x] + "\n")

 if key == "Canister Firmware":
     if data[x] != "3.5.0.20":
         sys.stderr.write("The Canister Firmware must updated to 3.5.0.20 it is currently" + data[x] + "\n")
```

f.close()

Comment: Can you clean up your formatting and indentation a bit?  It will be hard for anyone to help you without some cleanup.  You can edit your question by clicking the "edit" link below your `python` and `regex` tags.

Comment: Please [stop reposting your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810452/need-to-make-this-parsing-code-more-generic-using-regex).

Comment: answer it then @admdrew

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse with regexes. Besides requiring a PCRE version for context, they are [slow when used like this](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html). Have you looked into using [Ply](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/)? You are well on your way to rolling your own state machine, and the pain therein.

I have a [sample ply parser](https://github.com/srathbun/sample-ply-parser) you can use to get started. See how it uses simple regexes inside the `lexer.py` file to define tokens, which get handed to the `parser.py` file. The parser defines what order of tokens is valid, and what to do with sets of tokens.

This allows you to have code execute when you find a match, in the lexer, *and* when you have determined context, in the parser. For instance, you find a number in the lexer, and pass it to the parser. The parser sees the number token is after the processor token, and records it as relevant data.